# Restrict user access

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to restrict user access on edit button. In page designer, when I click on button there is security section. I can choose only one role, but I need to select more then one. How can I restrict button access for more then one role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create additional role which "combines" those you're interested in, and then apply that newly create role to the button.

Comment: Thank you! I thought there was a way to pick more then one role

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a way to pick more than one role. Use the `server side condition` with `PLSQL Expression` and use the `apex_authorization` api to combine your base authorizations.

Like this:

```
apex_authorization.is_authorized (p_authorization_name => 'FirstAuthorization')
OR apex_authorization.is_authorized (p_authorization_name => 'SecondAuthorization')
```

You can combine your Authorizations with `OR`, `AND` or even SQL conditions.
In my opinion, this approach is better than to have authorization roles for alle possible combinations.

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Thomas Tschernich    can you provide your input on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72936370/even-user-can-also-access-the-apex-page-need-to-restrict