# Even user can also access the APEX page need to restrict

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a application which as 4 pages

- Home
- Admin page
- Calculate BMI
- About

Then I went into `-> shared components -> Select Authorization schema -> Create`

I have set a name to it as `only_admin -> PLSQL boolen expression return (option)`

**Below is my code**

```
DECLARE
  myrole VARCHAR2(10 CHAR);
BEGIN
  SELECT role_assigned
  INTO   myrole
  FROM   employee
  WHERE  id = :APP_USER;
  
  IF :myrole = 'ADMIN' THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
  ELSE
    RETURN false;
  END;
```

After saving my above code … I went into `Admin page -> under security -> selected -> only_admin`

Now what is happening is … even the user is also able to see the page. That should not happen

**Below is my table : Employee **

```
NAME,AGE,ID,ROLE_ASSIGNED
Raj,22,12,ADMIN 
Deep,24,14,USER
Bob,26,16,USER
```

I want to restrict the Name : Deep and Bob from accessing the Admin page as they are `USER -> ROLE_ASSIGNED`

Comment: @Thomas Tschernich : Can you provide your input on this above question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not

```
IF :myrole = 'ADMIN' THEN
```

but

```
IF myrole = 'ADMIN' THEN
```

i.e. no semi-colon in front of `myrole`. It isn't a page item or anything like that; it's just a local variable.

Comment: Thank you … This was a silly mistake I made ha ha haa...

Comment: You're welcome. It happens ... referencing *this* and *that* in various tools can be tricky so - one has to be careful. It would be better if Apex raised an error (or warning, at least) that :MYROLE doesn't exist ...

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness here is another option that is both simpler and less error prone. As authorization scheme code, instead of using a "pl/sql function returning boolean", go for the "sql exists" option with the following sql:

```
SELECT  1 
  FROM  employee
 WHERE  id = :APP_USER 
   AND  myrole = 'ADMIN'
```

Advantages:

- If user has no row in table employee, it will not raise an exception.
- If the security model allows for an employee to have multiple rows, no change to the source is needed.